# How to find the height between a certain point in an iframe and the top of the iframe document

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe loaded in a parent window of a different domain, and I want to find the pixel height difference between any point in the iframe and the iframe's document height. By iframe document height, I don't mean just the top of the iframe, but the top of the document that is loaded inside of the iframe (which are different if you scroll down inside the iframe).

I want to be able to do this from within a script in the parent window's html. Using `$("iframe").offset().top` to find the top of the iframe's document doesn't work for reasons stated above (I don't want the top of the iframe). Is there a way to get the reference of the document DOM element that is loaded inside of the iframe, and would that help me?

Comment: Do you have control of the other domain? Communication between different windows on different domains is only possible if you configure both windows to communicate via messages.

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is on a different domain, you can't do it. It would require access to the `contentDocument` to get the `scrollTop` position. While obviously knowing where the document is scrolled isn't a compromise to a user's security, accessing `contentDocument` on another domain is a blanket no-no.

Now, if you had a PHP file on your domain, that proxied the page from the other domain, that's another story. Such a method would be simple to implement if you're only accessing one page with no links or forms:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/"); ?>
```

and...

```
<iframe src="myproxy.php" id="iframe" />
```

Now you can access the `contentDocument`, and therefore its contents:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.documentElement.scrollTop
// contentDocument.body.scrollTop in some browsers - get both and add them together
```

If there are links and/or forms, your life will be a lot more difficult. First you'd have to rewrite all URLs to go through your proxy script, then you'd have to use socket functions or cURL to `POST` form data to the other server... it'd just be a lot easier if you have only one page.